# Can I demand both MAC and credentials to access network using MS RADIUS server?

Tags: windows, radius, nps

Is is possible to demand both of these types of authorization? I know Microsoft NPS can use MAC address or credentials to approve access however can I demand both of these simultaneously?
Thanks, Majzlik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so, the docs [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753603.aspx) say "RADIUS Access-Request messages are processed or forwarded by NPS only if the settings of the incoming message match at least one of the connection request policies configured on the NPS server"